# Layouting issues with element that is newed in Code-Behind

Tags: maui

In my .NET MAUI App, I use a Popup from the Community Toolkit which is newed in Code-Behind after click on an icon and then resized to a certain percentage of the Screen in Portrait/Landscape-Orientation.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<toolkit:Popup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
           xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views;assembly=CommunityToolkit.Maui"
           xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls"
           xmlns:loc="clr-namespace:LocalizationResourceManager.Maui;assembly=LocalizationResourceManager.Maui"
           xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:OptimizerApp.ViewModels"
           xmlns:databaseModels="clr-namespace:OptimizerApp.DatabaseModels"
           x:DataType="viewModels:CustomPopupViewModel"
           x:Class="OptimizerApp.Pages.Views.Controls.CustomPicker.CustomPopup"
           CanBeDismissedByTappingOutsideOfPopup="False">

    <Grid x:Name="PopupParentGrid" RowDefinitions="Auto, *, Auto" Background="White" SizeChanged="PopupParentGrid_SizeChanged">

        <!-- SearchBar in first row -->
        <SearchBar Grid.Row="0" ios:SearchBar.SearchBarStyle="Minimal" Text="{Binding SearchText}" Placeholder="Saved item..." Margin="5"  />


        <!-- CollectionView in second row -->
        <CollectionView Background="Red" x:Name="PopupCollectionView" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding GroupedSavedItems, Mode=TwoWay}" IsGrouped="True" SelectionMode="Single" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSaved, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="20">

            <CollectionView.Resources>
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <Style TargetType="Label">
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
                    </Style>
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </CollectionView.Resources>

            
            <!-- Heading:  Group-Name, underlined -->
            <CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewModels:GroupedSavedItemList">
                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                        <Label FontAttributes="Bold" Text="{Binding GroupName, StringFormat=' {0}'}" TextColor="{StaticResource DarkOrange1}" Margin="0, 10, 0, 0" />
                        <BoxView HeightRequest="0.5" Color="{StaticResource Gray200}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0, 5, 0, 5" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>

            <!-- Items:   Name, LastSavedDate -->
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="{x:Type databaseModels:Saved}">

                    <SwipeView>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource LightOrange2}" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                        <SwipeView.RightItems>
                            <SwipeItems>
                                <SwipeItem Text="Delete" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource DarkOrange1}"
                                           Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewModels:CustomPopupViewModel}}, Path=DeleteSavedCommand}"
                                           CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                            </SwipeItems>
                        </SwipeView.RightItems>

                        <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*, Auto" Padding="5, 10" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                            <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding LastSavedDate, StringFormat='{0:d}'}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </SwipeView>

                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

        </CollectionView>
        
        
        <!-- Cancel/OK-Button -->
        <Grid x:Name="PopupButtonBar" Grid.Row="2" ColumnDefinitions="Auto, Auto" ColumnSpacing="5" HeightRequest="35" Margin="15" HorizontalOptions="End">

            <Grid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Setter Property="FontAutoScalingEnabled" Value="True" />
                    <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="35" />
                    <Setter Property="WidthRequest" Value="100" />
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="15, 7, 15, 10" />
                </Style>
            </Grid.Resources>

            <Button Grid.Column="0" Text="{loc:Translate CancelButtonText}" Clicked="CancelButton_Clicked" />
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Text="{loc:Translate OKButtonText}" Clicked="OkButton_Clicked" Command="{Binding OkButtonCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedSaved}" />

        </Grid>

    </Grid>

</toolkit:Popup>
```

**Code-Behind**

```cs
private void OnDropDownButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    customPopupViewModel.SelectedSavedMealName = Text;

    customPickerPopup = new CustomPopup();
    customPickerPopup.BindingContext = customPopupViewModel;
    
    AdaptPopupSizeBasedOnOrientation();
    customPickerPopup.Content.Focus();

    var mainPage = Application.Current.MainPage;
    mainPage.ShowPopupAsync(customPickerPopup);
}
```

```cs
private void AdaptPopupSizeBasedOnOrientation()
{
    var contentView = FindParentContentView(this);
    if (contentView.Height > contentView.Width)     // Portrait
    {
        customPickerPopup.Size = new Size(DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Width * 0.3, DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Height * 0.2);
    }
    else                                            // Landscape
    {
        customPickerPopup.Size = new Size(DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Width * 0.3, DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Height * 0.3);
    }
}
```

When I open my CustomPopup its content (defined in XAML-Code above) is not rendered correctly. I would expect the displayed Element "M1" and Date "16/20/2023" in Grid like last column is sized by the width of the Date and the first column takes the rest - first column should be stretched, but isn't

[image]

When I rotate my display nothing is stretched first of all. When I rotate further it's finally stretched correctly and stays like this. I also sometimes had the effect it even gets back to the its unstretched layout, when rotating further.

What can I do, that the layout is re-calculated correctly? Just guessing that newing and re-sizing my Popup in the Code-Behind causes it.

Thought, I could call ForceLayout() on the Grid, it does not offer ForceLayout() in my Code-Behind. I also added a ContentView and called ForceLayout() on this without impact.

***Interesting how the SearchBar is obviously streched (more precise - not streched - see line below the SearchBar)

Screenshots when I rotate left:

[image]

[image]

**Here it is as expected:**

[image]

[image]

============= Additional Code as asked in Comment =============

**CustomPickerControl:**

Popup is opened when the ImageButton is clicked in registered event:

```cs
imageButton.Clicked += OnDropDownButtonClicked;
```

```cs
namespace OptimizerApp.Pages.Views.Controls.CustomPicker
{
    using CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views;
    using OptimizerApp.Pages.Views.Controls.CustomEntry;
    using OptimizerApp.ViewModels;
    using Microsoft.Maui.Controls;

    public class CustomPickerControl : ContentView
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Text), typeof(string), typeof(CustomPickerControl), string.Empty);
        public static readonly BindableProperty PlaceholderProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Placeholder), typeof(string), typeof(CustomPickerControl), string.Empty);
        public static readonly BindableProperty BorderColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(BorderColor), typeof(Color), typeof(CustomPickerControl), Colors.Black);
        public static readonly BindableProperty BorderMarginProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(BorderMargin), typeof(Thickness), typeof(CustomPickerControl), new Thickness(0, -5, 0, 0));
        public static new readonly BindableProperty MarginProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Margin), typeof(Thickness), typeof(CustomPickerControl), new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0));


        public string Text
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
            set => SetValue(TextProperty, value);
        }

        public string Placeholder
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(PlaceholderProperty);
            set => SetValue(PlaceholderProperty, value);
        }

        public Color BorderColor
        {
            get => (Color)GetValue(BorderColorProperty);
            set => SetValue(BorderColorProperty, value);
        }

        public Thickness BorderMargin
        {
            get => (Thickness)GetValue(BorderMarginProperty);
            set => SetValue(BorderMarginProperty, value);
        }

        public new Thickness Margin
        {
            get => (Thickness)GetValue(MarginProperty);
            set => SetValue(MarginProperty, value);
        }

        private readonly CustomPopupViewModel customPopupViewModel;
        private Popup customPickerPopup;

        public CustomPickerControl()
        {
            customPopupViewModel = new CustomPopupViewModel();

            customPickerPopup = new CustomPopup();
            customPickerPopup.BindingContext = customPopupViewModel;

            var entry = new BorderlessEntry()
            {
                ClearButtonVisibility = ClearButtonVisibility.WhileEditing,
                PlaceholderColor = new Entry().PlaceholderColor
            };

            entry.SetBinding(Entry.TextProperty, new Binding(nameof(Text), source: this));
            entry.SetBinding(Entry.PlaceholderProperty, new Binding(nameof(Placeholder), source: this));
            entry.SetBinding(Entry.MarginProperty, new Binding(nameof(Margin), source: this));


            var grid = new Grid()
            {
                ColumnDefinitions = new ColumnDefinitionCollection
                {
                    new ColumnDefinition { Width = GridLength.Star },
                    new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) },
                },

                RowDefinitions = new RowDefinitionCollection
                {
                    new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto },
                    new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto },
                },
            };
            grid.Add(entry, 0, 0);

            var imageButton = new ImageButton
            {
                Source = "chevron_down_solid.png",
                HeightRequest = 11,
                WidthRequest = 11,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End,
                Margin = new Thickness(5, 0, 5, 0)
            };

            if (DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.iOS)
            {
                imageButton.Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit;
                imageButton.Scale = 0.35;
            }

            imageButton.Clicked += OnDropDownButtonClicked;

            grid.Add(imageButton, 1, 0);

            var boxView = new BoxView
            {
                HeightRequest = 0.5,
            };

            boxView.SetBinding(BoxView.ColorProperty, new Binding(nameof(BorderColor), source: this));
            boxView.SetBinding(BoxView.MarginProperty, new Binding(nameof(BorderMargin), source: this));

            Grid.SetRow(boxView, 1);
            Grid.SetColumn(boxView, 0);
            Grid.SetColumnSpan(boxView, 2);
            grid.Children.Add(boxView);

            Content = grid;
        }

        private void OnDropDownButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            customPopupViewModel.SelectedSavedName = Text;

            customPickerPopup = new CustomPopup();
            customPickerPopup.BindingContext = customPopupViewModel;

            AdaptPopupSizeBasedOnOrientation();

            var mainPage = Application.Current.MainPage;
            mainPage.ShowPopupAsync(customPickerPopup);
        }

        protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
        {
            base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);

            if (width < 0 || height < 0 || customPickerPopup == null)
                return;

            AdaptPopupSizeBasedOnOrientation();
        }

        private void AdaptPopupSizeBasedOnOrientation()
        {
            var contentView = FindParentContentView(this);
            if (contentView.Height > contentView.Width)     // Portrait
            {
                customPickerPopup.Size = new Size(DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Width * 0.3, DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Height * 0.2);
            }
            else                                            // Landscape
            {
                customPickerPopup.Size = new Size(DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Width * 0.3, DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Height * 0.3);
            }
        }

        private static ContentView FindParentContentView(Element element)
        {
            Element parent = element.Parent;

            while (parent != null)
            {
                if (parent is ContentView contentView)
                {
                    return contentView;
                }

                parent = parent.Parent;     // Check parent...
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**CustomPopupContentPage.xaml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<toolkit:Popup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
           xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views;assembly=CommunityToolkit.Maui"
           xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls"
           xmlns:loc="clr-namespace:LocalizationResourceManager.Maui;assembly=LocalizationResourceManager.Maui"
           xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:OptimizerApp.ViewModels"
           xmlns:databaseModels="clr-namespace:OptimizerApp.DatabaseModels"
           x:DataType="viewModels:CustomPopupViewModel"
           x:Class="OptimizerApp.Pages.Views.Controls.CustomPicker.CustomPopup"
           CanBeDismissedByTappingOutsideOfPopup="False">


    <Grid x:Name="PopupParentGrid" RowDefinitions="Auto, *, Auto" Background="White" SizeChanged="PopupParentGrid_SizeChanged">

        <!-- SearchBar in first row -->
        <SearchBar x:Name="SearchBar" Grid.Row="0" ios:SearchBar.SearchBarStyle="Minimal" Text="{Binding SearchText}" Placeholder="{loc:Translate CustomPickerPopup_SearchSavedPlaceholder}" Margin="5" />


        <!-- CollectionView in middle row -->
        <CollectionView Background="Red" x:Name="PopupCollectionView" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding GroupedSavedItems, Mode=TwoWay}" IsGrouped="True" SelectionMode="Single" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSaved, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="20" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" SizeChanged="PopupCollectionView_SizeChanged">

            <CollectionView.Resources>
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <Style TargetType="Label">
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
                    </Style>
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </CollectionView.Resources>

            
            <!-- Heading:  Group-Name, underlined -->
            <CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewModels:GroupedSavedItemList">
                    <!--VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"-->
                    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                        <Label FontAttributes="Bold" Text="{Binding GroupName, StringFormat=' {0}'}" TextColor="{StaticResource DarkOrange1}" Margin="0, 10, 0, 0" />
                        <BoxView HeightRequest="0.5" Color="{StaticResource Gray200}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0, 5, 0, 5" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>


            <!-- Items:   Name, LastSavedDate -->
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="{x:Type databaseModels:Saved}">
                    <SwipeView>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource LightOrange2}" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                        <SwipeView.RightItems>
                            <SwipeItems>
                                <SwipeItem Text="Delete" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource DarkOrange1}"
                                           Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewModels:CustomPopupViewModel}}, Path=DeleteSavedCommand}"
                                           CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                            </SwipeItems>
                        </SwipeView.RightItems>


                        <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*, Auto" Padding="5, 10">
                            <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                            <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding LastSavedDate, StringFormat='{0:d}'}" />
                        </Grid>

                    </SwipeView>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

        </CollectionView>
        
        
        <!-- Cancel/OK-Button -->
        <Grid x:Name="PopupButtonBar" Grid.Row="2" ColumnDefinitions="Auto, Auto" ColumnSpacing="5" HeightRequest="35" Margin="15" HorizontalOptions="End">

            <Grid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Setter Property="FontAutoScalingEnabled" Value="True" />
                    <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="35" />
                    <Setter Property="WidthRequest" Value="100" />
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="15, 7, 15, 10" />
                </Style>
            </Grid.Resources>

            <Button Grid.Column="0" Text="{loc:Translate CancelButtonText}" Clicked="CancelButton_Clicked" />
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Text="{loc:Translate OKButtonText}" Clicked="OkButton_Clicked" Command="{Binding OkButtonCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedSaved}" />

        </Grid>

    </Grid>

</toolkit:Popup>
```

**CustomPopupViewModel**

```cs
namespace OptimizerApp.ViewModels
{
    public partial class CustomPopupViewModel : ViewModelBase, INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {
        public ObservableRangeCollection<SavedItem> SavedItems { get; set; }

        public AsyncCommand<bool> RefreshCommand => new AsyncCommand<bool>(RefreshDatabase);
        public AsyncCommand<SavedItem> DeleteSavedItemCommand => new AsyncCommand<SavedItem>(DeleteSavedItem);
        public AsyncCommand OkButtonCommand { get; }   

        public string SelectedSavedItemName { get; set; }
        public SavedItem SelectedSavedItem { get; set; }

        double _height;
        public double Height
        {
            get => _height;
            set => SetProperty(ref _height, value);
        }

        double _width;
        public double Width
        {
            get => _width;
            set => SetProperty(ref _width, value);
        }

        public CustomPopupViewModel()
        {
            LanguageResourceManager = LanguageResourceManager.Instance;
            SavedItems = new ObservableRangeCollection<SavedItem>();
            OkButtonCommand = new AsyncCommand(OnOkButtonCommand);
            RefreshCommand.ExecuteAsync(true);            
        }

        private async Task RefreshDatabase(bool selectSavedItem = true)
        {
            IsBusy = true;

            var savedItems = await DatabaseService.GetSavedItems();
            SavedItems.Clear();
            SavedItems.AddRange(savedItems);

            GroupSavedItemsWithSearchFilter();       // Start with empty Search-Filter (=> get all Items)

            if (selectSavedItem)
            {   
                await SelectSavedItemByName(SelectedSavedItemName);
            }
            
            IsBusy = false;
            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private async Task SelectSavedItemByName(string savedItemName)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(savedItemName))
            {
                await SelectSavedItemByIndex(0);
                return;
            }

            SavedItem foundSavedItem = GroupedSavedItemItems.SelectMany(list => list).FirstOrDefault(savedItem => savedItem.Name == savedItemName);

            SelectedSavedItem = foundSavedItem;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedSavedItem));
            
            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private async Task SelectSavedItemByIndex(int index)
        {
            if (SavedItems.Count == 0)
            {
                SelectedSavedItem = null;
            }
            else if (SavedItems.Count >= 1)
            {
                if (index < 0)
                    index = 0;
                else if (index >= SavedItems.Count)
                    index = SavedItems.Count - 1;

                var selectSuccessor = SavedItems[index];
                await SelectSavedItemByName(selectSuccessor.Name);
            }

            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private async Task DeleteSavedItem(SavedItem ItemToDelete)
        {
            var indexOfItemToDelete = SavedItems.IndexOf(ItemToDelete);
            if (indexOfItemToDelete != -1)
            {
                await DatabaseService.DeleteItem(SelectedSavedItem);                
                await RefreshDatabase(false);
                await SelectSavedItemByIndex(indexOfItemToDelete - 1);
            }
            
            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }        

        public LanguageResourceManager LanguageResourceManager { get; }  
        private string _searchText;
        public string SearchText
        {
            get => _searchText;
            set
            {
                if (_searchText != value)
                {
                    _searchText = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SearchText));
                    OnSearchTextChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnSearchTextChanged()
        {
            GroupSavedItemsWithSearchFilter();
        }

        private ObservableRangeCollection<GroupedSavedItemItemList> _groupedSavedItemItems { get; set; }
        public ObservableRangeCollection<GroupedSavedItemItemList> GroupedSavedItemItems
        {
            get => _groupedSavedItemItems != null ? _groupedSavedItemItems : new ObservableRangeCollection<GroupedSavedItemItemList>();
            set
            {
                if (_groupedSavedItemItems != value)
                {
                    _groupedSavedItemItems = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(GroupedSavedItemItems));
                }
            }
        }

        private void GroupSavedItemsWithSearchFilter()
        {
            IOrderedEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, List<SavedItem>>> groupedSavedItemItemsDictionary;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchText))
            {
                groupedSavedItemItemsDictionary = SavedItems
                    .OrderBy(savedItemItem => savedItemItem.Name)
                    .GroupBy(savedItemItem => savedItemItem.Name.ToUpperInvariant().Substring(0, 1))
                    .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.ToList()).OrderBy(group => group.Key);
            }
            else
            {
                groupedSavedItemItemsDictionary = SavedItems
                    .Where(savedItem => savedItem.Name.ToLower().StartsWith(SearchText.ToLower()))
                    .OrderBy(savedItemItem => savedItemItem.Name)
                    .GroupBy(savedItemItem => savedItemItem.Name.ToUpperInvariant().Substring(0, 1))
                    .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.ToList()).OrderBy(group => group.Key);
            }

            GroupedSavedItemItems.Clear();

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<SavedItem>> item in groupedSavedItemItemsDictionary)
            {
                GroupedSavedItemItems.Add(new GroupedSavedItemItemList(item.Key, new List<SavedItem>(item.Value)));
            }
        }

        private async Task OnOkButtonCommand()
        {
            WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new SavedItemSelectionChangedMessage(SelectedSavedItem));
            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
                return false;

            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

===== Additional Code regarding comment =====

**ViewModelBase**

Just a Helper from MvvmHelpers

```cs
using MvvmHelpers;

namespace MacroOptimizerApp.ViewModels
{
    public class ViewModelBase : BaseViewModel
    {
    }
}
```

**GroupedSavedItemList**

This is a List to realize Grouping of the bound List, so that I have different sections and all items starting with A are grouped together, all items with B and so on

```cs
using OptimizerApp.DatabaseModels;

namespace OptimizerApp.ViewModels
{
    public partial class GroupedSavedItemList : List<SavedItem>
    {
        public string GroupName { get; set; }

        public GroupedSavedItemList(string groupName, List<SavedItem> item) : base(item)
        {
            GroupName = groupName;
        }
    }
}
```

**SavedItem**

Data class for saved items having a Name and different other values that will be stored in a database

```cs
using SQLite;
using SQLiteNetExtensions.Attributes;

namespace OptimizerApp.DatabaseModels
{
    [Table("SavedItems")]
    public class SavedItem
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]     // Primary Key will already be indexed in a Table
        public int Id { get; set; }


        public string Name { get; set; }   

        public DateTime LastSavedDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

        [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.CascadeInsert | CascadeOperation.CascadeRead | CascadeOperation.CascadeDelete)]
        public List<ItemSelection> SelectedItems { get; set; } = new List<ItemSelection>();
    }
}
```

Comment: . (I'll delete this comment later. This is just here so I'll get notified about what people ask or suggest.)

Comment: When is this function `OnDropDownButtonClicked` called? And could you please post the code of the viewmodel and the `CustomPopup.xaml` of `CustomPopup`?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT - I am sorry for responding so late. I added some Code to my original question. The relevant Code actually is really in CustomPopupContentPage.xaml as I think. The OnDropDownButtonClicked-Code is called from the ```imageButton.Clicked += OnDropDownButtonClicked;```-Event. ```OnDropDownButtonClicked```creates a new instance of the custom popup und Displays it as Popup via MainPage and also does the size adaptions. Hope this helps...

Comment: What's the code of `GroupedSavedItemList`,`SavedItem` and `ViewModelBase `?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT - I added the parts you asked for above in my question. The ```GroupedSavedItemList``` is used to group the items. Anyway, I don't think it has an impact on the problem I originally asked for, but maybe makes it easier for you if you want to try out something. To be honest, I currently have no idea why it is displayed like I described in my question which is a bit frustrating :(

Comment: Hi @OXO, thanks for your sharing your code, but your code involves a lot of things, such as `ItemSelected` is not clear. I can't spot problems based on your already shared code. If it is convenient for you, could you please post a basic demo so that we can reproduce this problem on our side?

Comment: The ItemSelected is not relevant for the scenario and also might other things that are not relevant for layouting. It is important though that we have an element in the GroupedSavedItems List as it will display its key as a GroupName and its value as a list of the items in this group. But for this just 1 item to initialize it is totally sufficient. Unfortunately, as it is bound to a Database it wouldn’t help I think. The SelectedItem is just the selected element as the name says. For the Layouting issue shown in the screenshots it is not needed and can be ignored/commented out as you need it

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT - I could try to prepare something for you when back home in September. You could let me know, what information exactly was missing for you?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT - I promised to come back to you with an example project: https://github.com/MAUIoxo/CollectionViewLayoutWrongApp_17609 - I don't know if you have some ideas for workarounds I could try? Here is the Github Issue I wrote https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/17609